# Xamarin forms: How to add tapped event on XamForms.Controls.Calendar specialdate?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using `XamForms.Controls.Calendar` package for showing calendar in my project. I am marking events on the calendar using the below code.

```
private void AddSpecialDateWithList(List<events> list)
{
    List<SpecialDate> newList = new List<SpecialDate>();
    foreach (events model in list)
    {
        string startDate = model.start;
        int startIndex = startDate.IndexOf('T');
        if (startIndex > 0)
        {
            startDate = startDate.Substring(0, startIndex);
        }

        string endDate = model.end;
        int endIndex = endDate.IndexOf('T');
        if (endIndex > 0)
        {
            endDate = endDate.Substring(0, endIndex);
        }
        List<DateTime> dates = GetDatesBetween(DateTime.Parse(startDate), DateTime.Parse(endDate));
        for(int i=0;i< dates.Count; i++)
        {
            var newDate = AddDate(dates[i], model);
            newList.Add(newDate);
        }
    }
    calendar.SpecialDates = newList;
}

private SpecialDate AddDate(DateTime dateTime, events model)
{
    SpecialDate newDate = new SpecialDate(dateTime)
    {
        Selectable = true,
        BackgroundPattern = new BackgroundPattern(1)
        {
            Pattern = new List<Pattern>
            {
                new Pattern { WidthPercent = 1f, HightPercent = 0.7f, Color = Color.White },
                new Pattern{ WidthPercent = 1f, HightPercent = 0.3f, Color = Color.Yellow, Text = model.title, TextColor=Color.Black, TextSize=10, TextAlign=TextAlign.LeftCenter},
            }
        }
    };
    return newDate;
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

When I tap a day having event(31 Jan having maths homework), I need to get the event id and all the other details associated with that event. How can I do this feature? Also is it possible to show month, week and day view in `XamForms.Controls.Calendar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the index of **SpecialDate** in your list in the event **DateClicked**

```
private void calendar_DateClicked(object sender, DateTimeEventArgs e)
{
    int num = 0;

    var specialList = calendar.SpecialDates;
    var date = e.DateTime;

    foreach(SpecialDate specialDate in specialList)
    {
        if(specialDate.Date.Year==date.Year&& specialDate.Date.Month == date.Month&&specialDate.Date.Day == date.Day)
        {
            events model = list[num];
            // do something you want 
        }
        else
        {
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is list[num] here?

Comment: List<events> list in your project

Comment: is it possible to show month, week and day view in XamForms.Controls.Calendar?

Comment: found a property named EnableTitleMonthYearView, what is the use of that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the plugin, you could have a try .